# Run library module as a script by cron (python -m)

Tags: python, cron

I created python library. In order to avoid install of executable python scripts I allowed library modules to work as executables. It is possible to run module as script with -m opion (python -m).
Manually everything works:

```
$ python -m Library.Core.Runner runFirst
```

But when I try to run this with cron it does not work:

```
*/5 * * * * /usr/bin/python -m Library.Core.Runner runFirst >> /var/log/MyProject/runFirst.log 2>&1
```

Output from /var/log/cron:

```
Jul 26 18:25:01 myhostname crond[23735]: (/usr/bin/python) ERROR (getpwnam() failed)
```

How can I fix it?

Environment: CentOS 7, Python 2.7.5

Comment: put `if __name__ == "__main__":` in your library, and below that invoke the function you want to run

Comment: It is actually the case. Inside Runner I have: imports, definitions of methods, definition of the main, and `if __name__ == "__main__":      main()`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Add user name to let cron run the task on behalf of him:

```
*/5 * * * * <username> /usr/bin/python -m Library.Core.Runner runFirst >> /var/log/MyProject/runFirst.log 2>&1
*/5 * * * * igor /usr/bin/python -m Library.Core.Runner runFirst >> /var/log/MyProject/runFirst.log 2>&1
```

Comment: in my case it was the user that I had to run the cron with, otherwise I was getting the error: (python) ERROR (getpwnam() failed)